# Converting between RAID controllers

Tags: raid

I have a server with an old and ailing Areca ARC-1231ML RAID controller card that I would like to exchange with a MegaRAID 9460-16i, ideally without losing all my data.

It appears that no readymade in-place conversion tools exist, or even format documentation for the on-disk formats that would allow me to write such a tool.

What would be the best way to migrate from one vendor to another?

Comment: What RAID mode are we talking about?

Comment: @Ramhound, RAID-6, because we love complicated.

Comment: How many drives?

Comment: @Ramhound, currently 8, between 2 and 4 TiB each (so 2 TiB used on each).

Comment: The only way I know how to do it, would involve using half of your existing RAID, and attempt to rebuild it using the new controller.